# How to display all process matching a pattern in the monit web interface?

Tags: monitoring, monit

I am using monit to monitor all my processes which is matched using.

```
check process [name] matching [process name pattern]
```

Monit is able to match using the pattern and "monit procmatch [process name pattern]" lists all the process.

The problem is it is not listing in the web interface, it just displays only the first process.

Is it possible to list all the process in web interface ?

How can I have start and stop commands in monit for all those processes which are matched ?

Answer (score 4):

Monit only checks the [first process matched](http://www.mail-archive.com/monit-dev@nongnu.org/msg01387.html) by the string. If you have any way to refine the pattern to be more unique, you'll have more success. From the `monit procmatch` output...

```
[root@abc ~]# monit procmatch dbc
List of processes matching pattern "dbc":
------------------------------------------
        /ppro/dbcfs/dbcfsrun 10.2.2.7 9586 dbcfs.cfg 9584:1 -ssl -sport
        dbc DMHOST start cron
        dbc
        dbc JOBMAN start cron
        dbc
        dbc
        /ppro/dbcfs/dbcfs -y
------------------------------------------
Total matches: 7
WARNING: multiple processes matched the pattern. The check is FIRST-MATCH based, please refine the pattern
```